# 409 Conflict on Joomla 4 administrator backend

Tags: administrator, joomla-4

I am building a site using Joomal 4. I developed it on my local and uploaded that to the server. All the public pages of the site are rendering properly, but when I try to open the `/administrator` page, the page opens without any asset files.

I checked the dev console and found that all the asset files are throwing the same error, 409 conflict. I am also getting the following error for template.min.js.

> Loading module from “`https://website.com/media/templates/administrator/atum/js/template.min.js?7024ff588011084e122412cfbe75cc3c`” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).

I did not made any additional changes to the site, how can I fix this issue?